# ResourcesNotFoundException at NinePatchDrawable

Tags: android, android-layout, exception, android-drawable

I am getting ResourcesNotFoundException when trying to get nine patch drawable at below line .Devices I am having this issue are LGE Nexus(Android 8) and Google Pixel(Android 10).Other devices on which I have tried it's working fine.

```
mRecyclerViewDragDropManager.setDraggingItemShadowDrawable(
                (NinePatchDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.material_shadow_z3));
```

Exception

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0800af
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID
#0x7f0800af
       at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValueForDensity(ResourcesImpl.java:204)
       at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:875)
       at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:818)
       at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:605)
       at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:463)
       at init(ImagesActivity.java:211)
       at onCreate(ImagesActivity.java:121)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

I have provided material_shadow_z3 in drawable-hdpi,drawable-mdpi,drawable-xhdpi,drawable-xxhdpi,drawable-xxhdpi.Like-

material_shadow_z3.xml

```
<nine-patch xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:src="@drawable/material_shadow_z3_mdpi"
    tools:ignore="unused" />
```

Update on basis of comment-

`material_shadow_z3_mdpi` is located in drawable-nodpi folder and is a 9-patch png image.Similarly I have `material_shadow_z3_xhdpi,material_shadow_z3xxhdpi,material_shadow_z3_xxxhdpi` located in same drawable-nodpi folder.

Similar to this -
https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview/tree/develop/example/src/main/res/drawable-nodpi

Comment: Why have you provided multiple versions of your nine-patch drawable? Where is your `@drawable/material_shadow_z3_mdpi` located?

Comment: @ymindstorm `material_shadow_z3_mdpi` is located in drawable-nodpi folder and is a 9-patch png image.Similarly I have `material_shadow_z3_xhdpi,material_shadow_z3xxhdpi,material_shadow_z3_xxxhdpi` located in same drawable-nodpi folder.Similar to this - https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview/tree/develop/example/src/main/res/drawable-nodpi

Comment: What is the name of the actual nine-patch drawable? It should be "material_shadow_z3_mdpi.9.png". It will be referenced as `@drawable/material_shadow_z3_mdpi` in the XML file as you have it. If you look lower in the logcat, you may see "<nine-patch> requires a valid 9-patch source image" which indicates this problem. You would see this only on devices that hit against the nodpi assets.

Comment: @Cheticamp 'material_shadow_z3_mdpi.9.png' is the name..Can you explain what's the problem?

Comment: Still a mystery. I do think that ymindstorm is onto something, though. You may have too many drawables that are just redundant and something is missing that is causing the problem. If the same 9-patch ( material_shadow_z3_mdpi.9.png) and XML (material_shadow_z3.xml) are appropriate for all densities, then place those two files in the drawable-anydpi folder and delete all the others. That is likely to fix the problem IMO.  Even if it doesn't, it is still the way to go.  Better yet, since the XML doesn't seem to do anything other than hold the 9-patch, get rid of it and use just the 9-patch.

Answer (score 3):

Not 100% sure what is causing the issue but my guess is that there is a problem with how you sorted your files and while you will have all files available for your local builds they may be unavailable on your user's installs due to them getting the optimized apk for their specific device if you are using app bundles.

---

In accordance with [the resource documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources) and [the nine patch guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#NinePatch) here is how you would usually place the resources.

### Option 1 - single 9patch image

If you have a 9patch image that can be scaled and stretched to be used in any density just place the `.9.png` in the `drawable` folder.

### Option 2 - different 9patch images for different densities

If there is some aspect of the 9patch that needs to be different based on the density you place one `.9.png` image in every relevant `drawable-<density>` folder. The system will load the relevant image at runtime or scale the best fit from another density if none was provided.

---

Using the  XML resource declaration only makes sense if you want to set dithering manually.

So for your use case: Delete the `material_shadow_z3.xml` and place the `material_shadow_z3<-xxx>.9.png` in the appropriate drawable folders without the density identifier. Even better if you can just use a single 9patch png if the image itself is not really density dependent (like e.g. a gray bar with edges for the shadow).